# Batch file for /f not escaping double quotes

Tags: batch-file

So I'm using curl to get a download link from GitHub which is frequently changing.
Using for /f I can split the string that curl returns by every front slash **'/'**

The variable I get looks like this

**v0.30.2">redirected<**

From this, I managed to extract the version using substring but it fails to work when the number of characters changes so I must manually edit the substring length.

**To the issue**
Im trying to implement a for /f to extract the numbers from the variable above so I need use theese signs as delimiters **v . "** however whenever I try to use that double quotation as a delimiter I get nowhere. I read that using the escape char is the way to go but I'm not having any luck. Can anyone help?

Latest attempt at cracking this looked like this:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myStr=v0.30.2^"^>redirected^<
for /f tokens^=1-3 delims^=^.^"^v %%A in ("%myStr%") do (
   echo %%A
   echo %%B
   echo %%C
)
pause
```

The expected output should then be

```
0
30
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed one more caret, as the expresssion `tokens=1-3 delims=.v"` needs to be one block for the parser.
Normally this is archieved by simply quote the block like in `FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=.v"`.
But in the special case where a double quote should be in the delimiter list, the outer quotes have to be omitted and instead the block has to be glued with carets.

```
for /f tokens^=1-3^ delims^...
```

And the expansion of myStr should be done by delayed expansion instead of percent expansion.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ^"myStr=v0.30.2">redirected<"
for /f tokens^=1-3^ delims^=^.^"v %%A in ("!myStr!") do (
   echo %%A
   echo %%B
   echo %%C
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :) May I ask why the tokens need escape? I get the equals sign but after the 3? is it an escape for the blank space that follows?

Comment: @AdisSibic I added more explanations. Btw I would prefere the solution of compo, as it's easier to understand and it doesn't rely on the double quote hack

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your `%myStr%` variable is actually part of a previous attempt to retrieve the string from a line. If that's the case then you could have further parsed that line to retrieve just the version number.

first like this:

```bat
Rem drop everything at the first doublequote
Set "myStr=%myStr:"="&:"%"
```

then this:

```bat
Rem keep everything from the first v
Set "myStr=%myStr:*v=%"
```

If you wanted to then just output the individual parts of it:

```bat
For %%A In (%myStr:.= %) Do Echo %%A
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I shall try to study it to understand :) I implemented previous solution